# parse query find always returns empty result

Tags: php, android, parse-platform

Hello I was trying to uses Parse.com's Cloud Code API and I was trying to create a code snippet that will query the data that shows in my data browser

My cloud code is

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getDriver", function (request, response){
    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    var lastlogin;

    //response.success({"obj":request.params.objectId}); //works

    query.equalTo("objectId",request.params.objectId);
    query.find({
        success: function(objs) {

            response.success({"driver_id":objs.length});

        },
        error: function(error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        }
    });
});
```

I am calling the cloud code with php curl , the code is

```
$ch =curl_init("https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getDriver/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,"ca-bundle.crt");

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Parse-Application-Id:   APPLICATION_ID','X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY', 'Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"objectId\": \"NDpoVvFcGP\"}");
  //execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

My problem is that the query always gives an empty result even though the correct objectId is being passed: NDpoVvFcGP

I cannot figure out this one. What might be the problem? Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error code and description? Always helpful to know exactly what the error was.

Comment: {"result":{"driver_id":0}}

Comment: And what do you mean by this line:  "//response.success({"obj":request.params.objectId}); //works" in your code?

Comment: It means that the object Id being passed in the curl code is being returned successfully in the cloud code if i uncomment that line

Comment: Oh, ok. So you verify that the user exists, but the driver_Id is not returned (resulting in a length of 0). Is the objectId you return the correct one in the database? Response.success() returning the correct objectId does not necessarily mean it is correct when you uncomment that line, as you are not actually querying the database for that object ID.

Comment: The objectId is correct, i am just copying and pasting from my data browser. I am not getting any rows for any objectId in the data browser. I am using a free account with parse.com by the way. Does that make any difference?

Comment: The data was saved in android and the class is called User. Can I save it under Installation and then query using that as Class Name?

Comment: Should you be using a ParseUser object, rather than query a "User" database. I've had both a ParseUser table and a User ParseObject table and it can be quite confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are querying the built-in User class, you should look at the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying).

Specifically you should create your User query as follows:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

Internally I think they use "_User" as the class name, which is why your query failed when using "User". Best to just use the documented and supported method of querying the User class.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with how you query for the user. Take a look at this example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("totalMileage", function( request, response ) {
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.id = request.params.userid;
  var query = new Parse.Query("Trip");
  query.include('user');
  query.equalTo("user", user);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
      for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i ) {
        sum +=  results[i].get("end") - results[i].get("start") ;
      }
      response.success( sum );
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("trip lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

First I declare a user object and then I set the id with the passed in param, then I include the **object** in the query.

If you want more info, I have a write-up [here](http://superrunt.com/javascript/parse.com/2014/05/28/parse-cloud-code-example.html).